# WPML Arabic support for WP PHOTO GALLERY PLUS text fields

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual, qtranslate-x

WPML Arabic support for WP PHOTO GALLERY PLUS text fields

[Images descriptions needs to be in Arabic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YExV.png)

I'm using "WP Photo Gallery Plus" for photo albums and "qTranslate x" for Multilingual WP site.

But Photo albums does not allow me to translate these text fields for Arabic website.

[image: Here is the Photo Gallery plugin create album text field]

I need help, how can I translate Images heading or there any configurations that I need to do for ACF qtranslate or Kindly redirect me to something helpful

Comment: where have you wrote the English headings?

Comment: Belongs on webapps IMO. It's about the interface Wordpress has, not about coding for wordpress or a website.